# how to show subreport footer in main report footer in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I want to show the sub totals of a sub report in the main report footer in `Access 2016`. I have a subreport as below.

```
Location1
Column A  ColumnB  column C

 Subtotal1 = sum(column B)  SubTotal2 = sum(column C)

Location2
Column A  ColumnB  column C

Subtotal1 = sum(column B)  SubTotal2 = sum(column C)
```

Subreport footer shows the grand totals of both locations.

The main report is made from this subreport. The subreport is repeated for each parameter of main report.I want the location wise sub totals to be shown on the main report footer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One method - as you don't know the count of records - is for each, to collect the sum values in an array or Collection.

Then, in the footer, have a textbox you fill with the collected lines.

Comment: Thanks. will try it.